# PHP max CPU usage

Tags: php, linux, cpu-usage

**When executing a stronk PHP script, it takes only 16% of my CPU usage, the script is too slow, I attempt to up the php.ini « memory_limit »,**

I think it was that, but always only *16%*, Even if I do it 4 times at the same time.

***Where’s the issue ?***

Thanks in advance

Comment: 16% of your whole CPU or 16% of one core? Either way, if the CPU is not the limiting factor then take a look at I/O (disk, network or even memory speed).

Comment: Thanks. No, it's really my whole CPU who create this limit. I don't understand why !